# Application does not see created file

Tags: java, file, sockets, tcp, zip

I have created an application which records two files (from mic and camcorder). The recording works fine, but now I need to zip the audio files and send the zip file to server.
Unfortunately the second created file is not visible to the app even though it is in the folder while checking in the file manager. I still get "no such file or directory" error. 
I tried to use the following line:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(file)));
```

but it did not help.

Here is a function which creates a WAV file, here I tried to use sendBroadcast:

```
private void copyWaveFile(int mic){

        FileInputStream in;
        FileOutputStream out;
        long totalAudioLen;
        long totalDataLen;
        long longSampleRate = RECORDER_SAMPLERATE;
        int channels = 2;
        long byteRate = RECORDER_BPP * RECORDER_SAMPLERATE * channels/8;

        byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];

        try {
            String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            File file = new File(getFilename(mic)); //getFilename returns filename for a given mic

            in = new FileInputStream(getTempFilename(mic));
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);

            totalAudioLen = in.getChannel().size();
            totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;

            WriteWaveFileHeader(out, totalAudioLen, totalDataLen,
                    longSampleRate, channels, byteRate); //here I write header for a WAV file

            while(in.read(data) != -1) {
                out.write(data);
            }

            in.close();
            out.close();
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(file)));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

here's the zipping function:

```
public void zip(ArrayList<String> _files, String zipFileName) {
        try {
            zipPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER + "/" + zipFileName;
            BufferedInputStream origin = null;
            FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(zipPath);
            ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(
                    dest));
            int BUFFER = 1024;
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];

            for (int i = 0; i < _files.size(); i++) {
                Log.v("Compress", "Adding: " + _files.get(i));
                FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(_files.get(i));
                origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER);

                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(_files.get(i).substring(_files.get(i).lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
                out.putNextEntry(entry);
                int count;

                while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                    out.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                origin.close();
            }

            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

but it does not work. Where is the bug?

Comment: `filepath` is unused.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you pass in an `ArrayList<File>` instead of `ArrayList<String>`. A `File` has more capabilities than a `String`, including the method `.exists()` which can tell you whether you've got the path correct in the beginning, before you start sending it all over the place and confusing yourself.